# API result not showing C# UWP

Tags: c#, api, uwp

**Hello everyone,**

I'm trying to use an API to show the current Bitcoin price.
The API returns the result and everything but it just won't show it on the UWP application.

The strange thing is that it did show the result one time but after that it never showed the result again.

- Yes the API is really fast.

**Here is my MainPage code:**

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Price { get; set; }

    private DispatcherTimer _timer;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this._timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        this._timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
        this._timer.Tick += OnUpdate;

        this._timer.Start();
    }

    private async void OnUpdate(object sender, object e)
    {
        this.Price = (await API.GetData(1))[0]["price_eur"];
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Price"));
    }
}
```

**Here is my API class code:**

```
class API
{
    public static async Task<List<Dictionary<string, string>>> GetData(int limit)
    {
        var url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?convert=EUR&limit=" + limit;

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync(url);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(result);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is my MainPage xaml code:**

```
<RelativePanel>
        <Rectangle x:Name="rctOrange" Fill="Orange" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="tbPrice" FontSize="80" Text="{x:Bind Price, Mode=OneWay}" RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith="rctOrange" RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWith="rctOrange"/>
</RelativePanel>
```

I hope you guys can find the problem because I'm getting crazy.

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: We cannot help you if you don't provide us with information as to what is going wrong. Simply asking "Why doesn't this work" is not on topic on this forum. Are there any errors, what have to debugged so far?

Comment: @Glubus There are no errors and the program starts normally. The API call returns the right information but the only problem is that it will not place the "price_eur" in the application.

Comment: I understand, but I'm trying to convey to you that we need more in order to help you. You're asking us to find a problem for you so that you/we can solve it. You need to come up with a concrete problem that you need help with, instead of leaving that job to this forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged on your page. You should create an ViewModel that implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
private async void OnUpdate(object sender, object e)
{
    this.Price.Value = (await API.GetData(1))[0]["price_eur"];
}

class PriceModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private string _value;
    public string Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            _value = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer helped me out a lot!